# Connection Logitech Group to HP notebook with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: webcam, logitech

I've bought Logitech group for start conference. I try to connect it to HP notebook with Ubuntu 18.04. I connected it correct and on speaker i do not see message, that connection fail - it is good. In the list of device Immediately after connection USB, disappearing all audio devices and all stay grey. When I visit Google Meet site to create conference, the site after approx 1 min say that nothing to connect (any audio devices found). So I need to ubplug Logitech USB and reboot notebook, after it system (notebook) sound appeared.

I wrote to logitech support, but maybe you have any other and faster solutions?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I've found is to downgrade/upgrade your kernel (assuming that you are on a 5.x kernel lower than 5.9).

I fixed it myself by downgrading from 5.x to 4.4.x, and according to https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203419, it should be working with kernel 5.9.0 now.